# How Replace string with php

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace this kind of a string:

```
https://r2---sn-vgqs7nez.c.docs.google.com/
https://r2---sn-testne4.c.docs.google.com/
https://r5---sn-vfghtgh.c.docs.google.com/
```

to this

```
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/
```

using php, help me please

Comment: Have you tried anything? https://eval.in/552474

Comment: I'm a fan of http://www.phpliveregex.com/ - you might try that

Comment: While I agree with voting to close this question, I *disagree entirely* with both of the proposed reasons. This question is not unclear (it's very clear!) and the answer is not too broad either (see the answer below!). It is however a "please write code for me", so I'm voting that way instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no attempt to solve the problem on its own, instead simply asking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to search and replace

```
$pattern = '/^(https:\/\/)[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+.docs.google.com\//g';
preg_replace($pattern, 'https://redirector.googlevideo.com/', $yourstring);
```

Proof:
http://regexr.com/3d71p

Comment: for example i have this code: $headers = get_headers('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uL9-VkpFd5uCWnRv3zb1xocfIrePQ8VpGN7RVe0EHbSb6LKQleSlNS31GTrPygeFGGJZ=m37', 1);
echo $headers['Location'];  in the result (location url) i need to replace r2---sn-vgqs7nez.c.docs.google.com  (and all variable urls) to redirector.googlevideo.com   help me!

Comment: @SandroMaglie Eric just provided you a "working" solution. If you don't know how to copy & paste, there's a much bigger problem here.